# Marvel protagonists whose actual names and aliases are the same

Tags: marvel

Almost every superhero (and super-villain) has an alias which they go by like **Tony Stark** as **Iron Man**, **Steve Rogers** as **Captain America**, **Otto Octavius** as **Doctor Octopus** etc. However, there a quite a few people whose actual name and the aliases (alter-egos) are the same. Some of them include:

> 1. ***Doctor Strange***
> 2. ***Thor***, ***Loki*** (Asgardians)
> 3. ***Jessica Jones***
> 4. ***Luke Cage*** (*also goes by Power-man but Luke Cage is more prominent*)
> 5. ***Doctor Doom*** etc.

Are there any other characters (*protagonists only*) in the Marvel multi-verse who match this criteria?

Comment: Thor does have an alternate identity of Dr.Donald Blake. But one could argue that it's merely a cover identity.

Comment: Sadly, Jessica Jones had an alternate wacky name too. “Jewel,” I believe.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SecretPublicIdentity

Comment: @Adamant: and for what the Netflix shows are concerned, Jessica Jones does not consider herself to be a hero, so she does not need an alias.

Comment: Isn't Dr strange using his made-up name

Comment: Luke Cage is also an alias; his real name is Carl Lucas. Though I suppose he did eventually change his legal name to match.

Answer (score 2):

Given that I'm not sure of what exact criteria you're looking for (especially: if there has never, ever been a change in the superhero/villain's alias), here's my list:

- **Elektra**, born Elektra Nachios, martial arts expert, leader of the Hand (sometimes), girlfriend of Daredevil (again, sometimes), etc, etc;
- **Jean Grey**, when not in Phoenix Form though. Agreed, she's also gone by Marvel Girl, but I think I've seen her referenced as "Jean Grey" more than "Marvel Girl";
- While we're on the mutants, it's worth mentioning **Emma Frost**, even though she went with White Queen at some point;
- pretty much all of the Guardians of the Galaxy: **Gamora**, **Groot**, **Adam Warlock** (formerly known as Him though), **Rocket Raccoon**... but okay, that's cheating :p
- EDIT: you mentioned Doctor Doom (who's technically Victor von Doom), so I think it's pretty fair that **Baron Zemo** (technically Helmut Zemo, or any of his ancestors who've beared the name) gets a pass.

Comment: Others: Vision (He's occasionally gone by "Victor Shade", but not often enough for most people to remember); Marvel's original Captain Marvel (He was a Captain in the Kree's military, and his name was Mar-Vell); Dr. Druid); Drax (in the comics, created from the corpse of Arthur Douglas, but doesn't really seem to remember much of his original life). Since the original post included antagonists: pretty much all monster-types (Fin Fang Foom, Xemnu, Goom, Googam, etc.); Oh, yeah - *Thanos*, kind of a notable one; Kraven (the Hunter; Doctor Faustus

Comment: Actually all that is raising an interesting question: when is a name an alias? I mean I think of Elektra as an alias as it's her name on the merc market,Doctor Strange has this superheroey ring to it, but Thanos I mean it's "just" Thanos. Doesn't feel like it could be any other identity or something. I'm not sure if I'm being clear?

Comment: "Luke Cage" and "Jessica Jones" are not aliases, but the character's legal names. Admittedly, it's not the name Luke was given at birth, but (in the comics at least) he did legally change it to Luke Cage. "Elektra" is the character's legal first name; it just happens to be more distinctive that, say, "Brittany". Similarly, "Thanos" is his given name. In the comics, he has a brother named "Eros", who adopted the super-hero alias of "Starfox".

Comment: mmm. electric nachos.

Answer (score 0):

A few more characters to add to the list:

- Mar-vell
- Nick Fury
- Maria Hill
- Black Bolt, in a way. That is short for his real name, Blackagar Boltagon
- Black Panther is a title of nobility, so depending on how you stretch it, it might be considered his name.
- Venom (the symbiont, not Eddie under it)