# Which MCU characters have not been referred to by their superhero name?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

There's a clear trend in the MCU, all the way back to the start of the whole thing with the iconic admission:

> I am Iron Man,

to eschew the "secret identity" trope and for characters to more generally go by their common name.

Nonetheless some characters are, in fact, referred to by their "superhero name" (e.g. Iron Man, Ant-Man, Spider-Man) or have only one name (e.g. Thor, Vision).   In other cases, the name might just be alluded to, not exactly as a name, but more as a wink to the audience.

**Which MCU superheroes have *not* been directly or indirectly referred to by their superhero moniker?**

Comment: Does Far From Home count, even though it has not yet been released? That's the first time anyone actual refers to Danvers as Captain Marvel, afaik.

Comment: Not a dupe but closely related : https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187489/marvel-protagonists-whose-actual-names-and-aliases-are-the-same

Comment: Scarlet Witch anyone??

Comment: Luke Cage = Power Man ☺ Jennifer Jones = Jewel

Comment: As an aside, the I am Iron Man line was ad libbed by Robert Downey Junior, the script was going to have him maintain his secret identity but after filming the scripted version RDJ wanted to try different things. It wasn't until Kevin Feige saw the line during editing that the decision was made to take a risk and let the MCU know who these superheroes where, its why Thor is Thor and not Dr Donald Blake

Comment: @ThePopMachine that aged well ...

Comment: So, just to clarify: is it MCU _characters_ or MCU _Superheroes_ only?

Comment: @Möoz:   As I commented below, it wasn't my intent that they had to be heroes.   I was using "superhero name" to represent their "comic book" name or what have you.    But TheLethalCarrot assumed I meant to ask about specifically heroes and not villains.   If you would like to write an additional answer about villains, it would be welcome.

Answer (score 18):

**Quicksilver:** His only appearance is in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and he is only called by his real name.

**Wasp:** Whilst Janet was called Wasp on screen Hope has yet to be called it on screen if I'm remembering correctly.

**Smart Hulk:** Depending on how you think about this one, Banner/Hulk as Smart Hulk isn't referred to as Smart Hulk on screen. Dubious as to whether or not that counts though because he is still Bruce Banner/Hulk.

**Rescue:** Pepper dons the Rescue armour in *Avengers: Endgame* but it is up to you whether you count her as Rescue at that point or not.

**Adam Warlock:** In one of the post credits scenes to *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 2* the High Priestess has created a new birthing pod and calls the creation inside "Adam". This is almost certainly Adam Warlock but as it isn't 100% confirmed and we won't know if he'll be good or bad, if he ever shows up, I'm not sure if he counts.

**Howard the Duck:** Whilst his MCU appearances have so far been limited to cameos according to [Joe Russo](https://www.cbr.com/avengers-endgame-howard-duck-cameo/) he is [one of the heroes in the final battle of *Avengers: Endgame*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFwa7.jpg) so he should count and is never referred to at all if I'm remembering correctly.

---

To be complete the following are the super heroes who's super hero name we do know of from the films.

- **Iron Man:** Tony is constantly referred to it and calls himself it at the end of *Iron Man*.
- **Hulk:** Banner describes him and Hulk as really two different "people" sharing the same body but Hulk is called Hulk. The Grandmaster also refers to him as *The Incredible* Hulk in *Thor: Ragnarok*.
- **Captain America:** Captain America is Steve's "stage name" before he decides to give up his life of entertainment.
- **War Machine:** Tony calls Rhodey War Machine in *Iron Man 2* but this is *before* he becomes the superhero so up to if that counts. Although he is called War Machine later on a few times in *Iron Man 3* and is named as the Iron Patriot for a bit there too.
- **Thor:** It's his name so obviously he goes by it.
- **Assorted Asgardians:** Loki, the Warrior's Three, Lady Sif, Heimdall and Odin all fight for the good side, in Loki's case it changes, but again they all go by their actual names.
- **Black Widow:** She is named as Black Widow in *The Avengers* by Lychkov albeit in Russian.
- **The Winter Soldier:** Whilst Bucky is not technically a super *hero* at this point he is called The Winter Soldier in the film and later becomes a super hero.
- **Falcon:** Sam is named Falcon by Maria Hill 3 times in the film and the project he came from is named Falcon.
- **Star-Lord:** Peter calls himself Star-Lord in the opening sequence to *Guardians of the Galaxy* although no one else really knows the name.
- **Drax the Destroyer:** One of the prison inmates, forget if they are named, gives him the full title of Drax the Destroyer.
- **Assorted Guardians:** The rest, Gamora, Rocket, Groot and Yondu all go by their names.
- **Hawkeye:** Laura, his wife, calls him Hawkeye in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.
- **Vision:** He's called "my Vision" and similar a few times in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* but eventually throughout the later films is referred to as only Vision.
- **Ant-Man:** Both Scott and Hank have been called Ant-Man during their times wearing the suit.
- **Wasp:** Janet is called Wasp when Hank re-tells the story to Hope in *Ant-Man*.
- **Ghost:** Ava is named Ghost a few times throughout *Ant-Man and the Wasp*.
- **Black Panther:** He is named Black Panther a few times in *Black Panther*.
- **Assorted Wakandans:** Again here they all go by their real names.
- **Spider-Man:** He calls himself Spider-Man after Tony refers to him as Spider-Boy in *Captain America: Civil War* and is called by that name more times throughout the series.
- **Doctor Strange:** Technically it is his real name and his super hero name so he gets called by it a few times.
- **Ancient One:** She is called Ancient One throughout *Doctor Strange* and during her later appearances.
- **Wong:** This is his real name, per my understanding.
- **Nebula:** She is referred to it all the time.
- **Mantis:** Her real name so is referred to it all the time.
- **Kraglin:** His real name so is referred to it all the time.
- **Valkyrie:** She is called "a Valkyrie" in *Thor: Ragnarok* as the Valkyrie was a group. However, in *Avengers: Endgame* Smart Hulk calls her Valkyrie.
- **Korg/Miek:** It's their real names and they avoid most fights in their appearances so up to you if you include them.
- **Captain Marvel:** Whilst never referred to as Captain Marvel in *Captain Marvel* in the *Spider-Man: Far From Home* trailer Peter refers to her as such as do later works.
- **Scarlet Witch:** She is called a witch a few times and now in *WandaVision* has been referred to as the Scarlet Witch by Agatha.

Comment: "superhero name" was meant to refer to their out-of-universe alias.  It wasn't necessary to focus so much on whether a particular character is a hero or a villain.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I've only included the heroes in my answer because that is what your question asks for, I included "all" of them to be complete and to show evidence for why some aren't included because they have been called by their name. Asking a new question about the supervillains might be quite interesting though.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some which I can remember:

---

#### Scarlet Witch

Has been always addressed as "Wanda"  (in *Avengers: Age of Ultron, Captain America: Civil War, Avengers: Infinity War, Avengers Endgame*)

**Update**:

> Wanda was addressed by Agatha Harkness as ***The Scarlett Witch*** in Season 1: Episode 8 of *WandaVision*.

> "*Your children... And Vision.. And this whole little life you've made. This is chaos magic, Wanda. And that makes you The Scarlett Witch*"
>   <sub>*Agnes, Season 1: Episode 8*</sub>

#### Quicksilver

Has been addressed as "**Pietro**" (*Avengers: Age of Ultron*)

#### Carol Danvers/Captain Marvel

Although,

> She has been referred to as Captain Marvel in the recent *Spider-man: Far From Home* trailer

---

From *The Avengers*:

#### <s>Clint Barton/Hawkeye</s>

He is only addressed once in *The Avengers* but not as Hawkeye; always been referred to as Agent Barton or simply Clint.

> Fury: Where's Agent Barton?

> Dr. Selvig: *The Hawk*? Up in his nest, as usual.

> Fury: Agent Barton, report to me.

However,

> He does call his daughter Lila Barton as Hawkeye once in *Endgame* (right before she was dusted)

However, he has been called Hawkeye once by his wife Laura in *Age of Ultron*

> Laura Barton: You are so cute.

> Clint Barton: Nat and...and Banner?

> Laura Barton: I'll explain when you're older, **Hawkeye**.

> Clint Barton: Oh. Okay.

#### <s>Falcon</s>

Although his suit has been mentioned as the Falcon suit in *Captain America: The Winter Soldie*r, he himself has always been always addressed as "**Sam**"

However, in *Ant-Man*, Scott Lang refers to Sam as Falcon once; but I cannot conclude if Sam has been ever *officially branded* as "**The Falcon**" in the movies:

> Voice over Radio: [on Sam’s radio] What’s going on down there, Sam?

> Scott Lang: It’s the **Falcon**!

---

Also, something [*interesting*] :

#### Iron-Spider

Although in *Avengers: Infinity War*, the script [here](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War) says:

> [Iron Man fires a rocket from his shoulder which pierces the side of the ship to Maw's right and begins to suck everything out with depressurization, especially Maw and his large objects. Strange is pulled loose of his pinnings, loses the needles, but also heads for the hole, helpless to resist. The Cape wraps around his arm and an anchor point, but Strange's arm slips loose and he keeps going. Spider-Man shoots a web strand at Strange with one hand and holds onto a piece of the ship with the other. It breaks, sending them both towards space when his ***Iron-Spider suit***'s metal arms brace him to keep him from being sucked out. Fortunately, Strange is still surrounded by the ship's atmosphere making haste to leave.]

This version of Spider-Man has never been called as Iron-Spider in the movie.

Comment: Does Dr. Strange count?

Comment: @CBredlow he's been called Dr. Strange (and Sorcerer Supreme) so i don't think so. The OP asks about the characters who haven't been called using their superhero/code-names.

Comment: Evidence so far eliminates Hawkeye and Falcon.

Comment: Also Maria Hill calls Sam Falcon in TWS.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I have struck those names off but kept them in the answer. thanks for pointing them out

Comment: @Shreedhar:  I don't really think "Iron-Spider" is enough a superhero name to be mentioned.   This character is still Spider-Man in-universe.

Comment: You know, I can't think of a time anyone actually calls T'Challa Black Panther - he uses the term ("The mantle of the Black Panther has been passed down..."), but is it ever used as a name?

Comment: In universe, Peter Quill in Guardians of the Galaxy makes several references to how no one knows or calls him by his "super hero" name, Star Lord. I suppose that counts as an indirect reference though.

Comment: FWIW Wanda is referred to as a witch a few times but not to her face.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot as a witch, yes.. but never as Scarlet Witch.

Comment: @Shreedhar Oh I know worth mentioning though as I have done in my answer.

Comment: @MartianInvader:  We are talking about both direct and indirect references, so refering to "the mantle of the Black Panther" is good enough.

Comment: Wanda has now been called Scarlet Witch if you want to update this.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it happened in "Endgame", which I haven't seen yet (don't worry about spoiler, I already know what happens), Carol Danvers has not been called "Captain Marvel" by anyone in the MCU on screen. Similar point if Pepper Potts was not called "Rescue".

Comment: Does not happen in EG, but happens in the trailer for the next Spider-Man movie.

Comment: Well for rescue, I don't want to spoil it, but I'm not sure she deserve that name. But that's another point. She is not named in Endgame

Comment: @Jenayah: of course, it might not happen in the actual movie. See Nat at the shooting range in an *Endgame* trailer, and Hulk in Wakanda in an *Infinity War* trailer.